# child already has a parent error showing?

Tags: android, imageview

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container,false);
    ImageView tv = (ImageView ) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    tv.setImageResource(R.drawable.h1);
    return tv;
}
```

why am i getting the runtime error?

Comment: return v? did you mean this?

Comment: Include more info, please, and you'll get help. *Exactly* what error are you getting? Include the stack trace. (Guess, return v and not tv, but impossible to tell.)

Comment: thanks..such a stupid mistake by me. You are correct it should be "return v"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your above code as below:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container,false);
    ImageView tv = (ImageView ) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    tv.setImageResource(R.drawable.h1);
    return v;
}
```

The Reason you are getting RuntimeError is you are returning `ImageView` (tv) for `onCreateView` which is view for `Fragment`. But `ImageView` is a child View of `myfragment` layout so It cannot be set as `View` to `Fragment` so you are getting Runtime Error.

Comment: did you actually changed anything ?